# Display multiple Intent based items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to `populate` an `ArrayList` with some `Objects` that are set in another Activity. I am currently passing the data to my `MainActivitys ArrayList` via an `Intent` like so:

```
protected void populateTransactionList() {

    Intent depositIntent = getIntent();
    float addableValue = depositIntent.getFloatExtra("depositValue", 0);

    if (addableValue != 0){
        myTransactions.add(new Transaction(addableValue, 16, "random comment"));
    }
```

It works just fine. I get the correct view in my app. But as soon as I want to add another `item` to my `ArrayList`, it replaces the old one (which makes sense but) how am I able to display all of the `items`?

Comment: adding an item should not replace the old one. I suspect you are initializing a new Arraylist each time, but I can't be sure from the code you posted

Comment: By passing the array in the intent, you are creating a copy of it. So the one you're adding to doesn't have any effect on the copy. You should consider having your list accessible to both activities rather than passing via an intent.

Comment: Okay but how am I able to access the list from both activities?

Comment: One way to solve this is to maintain the list in calling activity and pass it to called activity every time it is called.

Comment: Wouldn't that just 'move' my problem in the code? I got an idea: is it possible that if the activity that sets the variables  closes the MainActivity gets reloaded so it just gets the last item added to it?

Comment: @lukas you can create a static arraylist in one of the activities...that way,  it will be available to both activities.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
//set list
Intent intent = new Intent();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 bundle.putStringArrayList("list",list);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

//get list on other activity
list = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
```

Note: you can choose different method for different list type as i have used "putStringArrayList"

Comment: At the get line it says that it requires an Integer but it gets an ArrayList.

Comment: you can change method as per your data type on bundle like putIntegerArrayList and on other side getIntegerArrayList